# When adding a date to a list how do I change what the user enters?

Tags: list

Ok so I have a list with various fields, one of which is date. When the user enters a date I want the date that gets displayed to be 3 days later than what they enter.

So far I've only played around with the validation as thats the only place I can see to enter and code into, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you are provisioning your list in Visual Studio, you could [add feature event receivers to the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx) that modify the data on the insert/update operations performed by users. The article linked to should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create a calculated column that takes the value of that date and adds 3 days, =[Column]+3.  Manipulating the user input can cause confusion for them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx

Comment: Where do I enter the formula on the sharepoint?

Comment: You create a new calculated column in the list itself.

Comment: Ok, sorry to sound stupid :P but how do I do that?

Comment: Go to your list and either go to Actions, Create Column if in 2007 or the List tab in the ribbon and click Create Column if in 2010.